# Can I use EKEvent in RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, ekevent, ekeventkit

I'm developing a Calendar app on iOS. In my application, I'm using `EKEvent` as event model. Since `EKEvent` is not a normal core data model, for example we should use `eventWithEventStore:` not `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` to create event, I'm not sure whether it's ok if I map some fields of `EKEvent` in RKObjectMapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to do a bit of work to make it ok. In particular you would need to create your own data source for the mapping so it can create (or find the existing event to update) events and return them to be updated by the incoming data.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I still get confused here. In your experience, should I use EKEvent or re-implement a new Event model? If the former, could you share more information about how to make it ok? If the latter, do you know any open source project working on this?

Comment: Personally I would probably wrapper, it's less code and allows you to work at a higher level of abstraction in restkit. I don't know of any project working on it, but it's really just a class with a property for the event and a set of methods forwarding data on yo it.

Comment: Got it, if so, I have another question about how to implement event model, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562394/whats-the-best-way-to-show-recurring-events-in-uitableview